# Burger button not centering on navigation bar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/my.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="100">
        <!- Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light" style="background-color:purple;">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right my-sm-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav" aria-controls="mainNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navber-brand" href="#">
                <img src="qlip.png" style="height:60px;">
            </a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the window is full size, all the links are center aligned.But when I make the window smaller, the burger icon does not align to the center of the navbar. How do I resolve this?

Comment: What burger icon are u talking about? And pls update you code snippet as there are errors with your libraries.

Comment: There is error with your snippet. Please, rectify it and re-post so that we can see your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your CSS from:

```
.navbar-toggler-right {
right : 2rem
```

}

to:

```
.navbar-toggler-right {
position: absolute;
right: 18rem;
left: 18rem;
top: 3px;
```

}

it will center.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-toggler-right {
position: absolute;
left: 50% !important;
top: 15px;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Personal Portfolio</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="/js/my.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="100">
            <!- Navbar-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light" style="background-color:purple;">
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right my-sm-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav" aria-controls="mainNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navber-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="qlip.png" style="height:60px;">
                </a>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </body>
    </html>
```